# Web Scraping Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

dears
I would like to scrape this site.
But can't this pls help
I want if

```
td= 'Legal Adress'
```

then export

```
"AZ1025, Baku city, Khatai District, Suleyman Vazirov, house 1170th quarter, 3-4th block, 1st floor"
```

if

```
td='Actual Adress'
```

then export

```
"AZ1025, Baku city, Khatai District, Suleyman Vazirov, house 1170th quarter, 3-4th block, 1st floor"
```

```
   [<div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
 <table class="table table-bordered">
 <!--
                      <tr>
                          <td width="20%">Seller</td>
                          <td>CYBERNET MƏHDUD MƏSULİYYƏTLİ CƏMİYYƏTİ</td>
                      </tr>
                      -->
 <tr>
 <td>Legal Adress</td>
 <td>AZ1025, Baku city, Khatai District, Suleyman Vazirov, house 1170th quarter, 3-4th block, 1st floor</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Actual Adress</td>
 <td>AZ1025, Baku city, Khatai District, Suleyman Vazirov, house 1170th quarter, 3-4th block, 1st floor</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Description</td>
 <td>  Cybernet LLC is one of the leading companies providing Information Technology services and solutions in Azerbaijan. Working mainly on Software Development, Modeling System Architecture and Building IT Infrastructure company offers innovative software and advanced hardware application, improvement, technical support and integration services for Government, Bank, Telecommunication, Large and Medium-sized Business organizations on Corporate management, finance and automation of business. Cybernet specialized in automation of Government services and creation of electronic services in Azerbaijan.<br/>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td width="30%">TIN</td>
 <td>9900050571</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td width="20%">Activity Group</td>
 <td>58290 - Publication of other software products</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>E-mail</td>
 <td>office@cybernet.az</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Phone</td>
 <td>+994124038963</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Mobile</td>
 <td>+994505891920</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Facebook</td>
 <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/cybernet.az/" target="_blank">https://www.facebook.com/cybernet.az/</a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Website</td>
 <td><a href="http://cybernet.az/" target="_blank">http://cybernet.az/</a></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>]
```

Comment: what have you tried? Please post your own code before asking. This is not a Q&A website. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You named that list son, so:

```
for td in son:
    for address in td.find_all("td"):
        if address.text == "Legal Adress" or address.text == "Actual Adress":
            print(address.find_next_sibling("td").text)
```